# if statement not controlling motor like expected

Tags: python, if-statement

I am having an issue where when i return 2 variables from one class to another function causing it to run it doesn't seem to run properly. I think the issue is with my if statement but i cant get it to work. when i print the variables before the if statement they show the correct things. however when i moved the print section into the statement it showed that only the else part was running every time. it is the MotorControl function i am referring to, i included the rest in case the issue lies else where.

These set of functions control the pin inputs which choose the direction of the motor.

```
def clockwise():
    io.output(in1_pin, True)
    io.output(in2_pin, False)

def counter_clockwise():
    io.output(in1_pin, False)
    io.output(in2-pin, True)

def stop():
    io.output(in1_pin, False)
    io.output(in2_pin, False)
```

This class is my server section of a socket server which receives the control commands from another program running on my laptop.

```
class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        self.DriveSend = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        self.SteeringSend = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        #print("{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0]))                
        self.SteeringSend = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        #print("{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0]))
        #print(self.DriveSend)
        #print(self.SteeringSend)
        #self.request.sendall(self.DriveSend.upper())
        #self.request.sendall(self.SteeringSend.upper())
        MotorControl(self)
        return (self.DriveSend,self.SteeringSend)
```

This function takes the return outputs from the server class and is meant to cause the clockwise and anticlockwise functions to cause the motors to turn 'forward' and 'reverse'.

```
def MotorControl(motor_var):
    speed = 1
    #print(motor_var.SteeringSend)
    #print(motor_var.DriveSend)
    print('test')
    Drive = str(motor_var.DriveSend)
        if Drive == "reverse":
            speed = 99
            print(Drive)
            counter_clockwise()
        elif Drive == "forward":
            speed = 99
            print(Drive)
            clockwise()
        else:
            stop()
    set("duty", str(speed))
```

Comment: So what is printed for the value? And have you checked that it does not include spaces, return characters, etc?

Comment: I have just checked this now and there may have been extra return characters in each however removing that did not make any difference. What i think may have happened is the variables seem to have swapped over so drivesend is now the steering variable :S any idea why this happened or how to change it? i am going to test this out now